# Como se puede exportar archivo csv con asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

Buenas quisiera que me puedan estoy realizando un aplicativo por la cual tiene la funcionalidades de descargar un archivo en **Formato Archivo de valores separados por comas de Microsoft Excel (.csv)** 
ya definidas la columnas en ese archivo una vez que se descargue el usuario con esa ya plantilla tiene que escribir y guardar.

el problema es que cuando descargo el excel.
sale esto como vista previa que esta en la derecha

Pero cuando entro a la mismo archivo se aparece bien.
Ahora ese archivo yo lo ingreso y lo muestro en mi gridview

Claro como sale algo raro en la vista previa en el gridview tambien sale lo mismo

Estoy usando la dll **ClosedXML.Excel;**

adjunto la imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Codigo que estoy realizando es el siguiente para crear el archivo csv**

```
 var wb = new XLWorkbook();
            var ws = wb.Worksheets.Add("Contacts");
            ws.Cell("A1").Value = "Fecha_Nacimiento";
            ws.Cell("B1").Value = "Número";
            ws.Cell("C1").Value = "Familia";
            ws.Cell("D1").Value = "Dni";
            ws.Cell("E1").Value = "Ruc";
            ws.Cell("F1").Value = "Apellido_Paterno";
            ws.Cell("G1").Value = "Apellido_Materno";
            ws.Cell("H1").Value = "Nombres";
            ws.Cell("I1").Value = "Celular";
            ws.Cell("J1").Value = "Correo";
            ws.Cell("K1").Value = "Dirección";
            Dtset.Tables[0].TableName = "Persona";

            Response.Clear();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Reporte.csv");

            using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
                MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
                Response.Flush();
                Response.End();
            }
```

**Código para que muestre a la grilla.**

```
 string csvPath = Server.MapPath("~/MyFolder/") + Path.GetFileName(inputGroupFile01.PostedFile.FileName);
                        inputGroupFile01.SaveAs(csvPath);
                        Label1.Text = inputGroupFile01.FileName + "\'s Información Cargada del excel.";
                        System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();


                        dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[11] { 
                        new DataColumn("Fecha_Nacimiento", typeof(string)),  
                        new DataColumn("Número", typeof(string)),  
                        new DataColumn("Familia", typeof(string)),  
                        new DataColumn("Dni", typeof(string)),  
                        new DataColumn("Ruc",typeof(string)),
                        new DataColumn("Apellido_Paterno",typeof(string)),
                         new DataColumn("Apellido_Materno",typeof(string)),
                         new DataColumn("Nombres",typeof(string)),
                         new DataColumn("Celular",typeof(string)),
                         new DataColumn("Correo",typeof(string)),
                          new DataColumn("Dirección",typeof(string))
                        });

                        string csvData = File.ReadAllText(csvPath, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"));

                        foreach (string row in csvData.Split('\n'))
                        {
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row))
                            {
                                dt.Rows.Add();
                                int i = 0;
                                foreach (string cell in row.Split(','))
                                {
                                    dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][i] = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(cell);
                                    i++;
                                }
                            }
                        }


                        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                        ds.Tables.Add(dt);

                        try
                        {
                            var results = from row in ds.Tables["Table1"].AsEnumerable() where row.Field<string>("NOMBRES") == "NOMBRE" select row;
                            foreach (DataRow row in results)
                            {
                                ds.Tables["Table1"].Rows.Remove(row);
                            }
                        }
                        catch { }

                        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                        GridView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solución para exportar con el formato CSV

lo que tenia que realizar o lo que estaba fallando era que también cuando se exporta con csv que es determinado o separado por comas debemos realizar el mismo formato a la columnas que se va exportar 
 que realice este código.

```
 builder.Append(string.Join(",", columnNames.ToArray())).Append("\n");

            foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
            {
                List<string> currentRow = new List<string>();

                foreach (DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)
                {
                    object item = row[column];

                    currentRow.Add(item.ToString());
                }

                rows.Add(string.Join(",", currentRow.ToArray()));
            }

            builder.Append(string.Join("\n", rows.ToArray()));





private System.Data.DataTable GetData()
        {
            System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable("Plantilla");
            dt.Columns.Add("Fecha_Nacimiento");
            dt.Columns.Add("Numero");
            dt.Columns.Add("Familia");
            dt.Columns.Add("Dni");
            dt.Columns.Add("Ruc");
            dt.Columns.Add("Apellido_Paterno");
            dt.Columns.Add("Apellido_Materno");
            dt.Columns.Add("Nombres");
            dt.Columns.Add("Celular");
            dt.Columns.Add("Correo");
            dt.Columns.Add("Direccion");
            dt.Columns.Add("Razon_Social");

            return dt;
        }



var dataTable = GetData();
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            List<string> columnNames = new List<string>();
            List<string> rows = new List<string>();

            foreach (DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)
            {
                columnNames.Add(column.ColumnName);
            }

            builder.Append(string.Join(",", columnNames.ToArray())).Append("\n");

            foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
            {
                List<string> currentRow = new List<string>();

                foreach (DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)
                {
                    object item = row[column];

                    currentRow.Add(item.ToString());
                }

                rows.Add(string.Join(",", currentRow.ToArray()));
            }

            builder.Append(string.Join("\n", rows.ToArray()));

            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=Plantilla.csv");
            Response.Write(builder.ToString());
            Response.End();
```

Comment: Agrega el detalle del cambio :D

Comment: @fredyfx listo hermano :D

Answer (score -1):

AL momento de crear el archivo, haz todo dentro del memory stream.

```
    List<byte[]> lista = new List<byte[]>();
    using(var exportData = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    this.Response.Clear();
                    package.SaveAs(exportData);
                    lista.Add(exportData.ToArray());
                    this.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                    this.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename={0}", package.Workbook.Worksheets.FirstOrDefault().Name + ".xlsx"));
                    this.Response.BinaryWrite(exportData.ToArray());
                    this.Response.End();
                    return exportData;                   
                }
```

this es el controlador.

Comment: quiero descargar en archivo csv

Comment: ademas cuando habro el archivo si sale correctamente pero en la vista previa sale mal.
y no es mvc sino en asp.net c#

Comment: Igual usas el MemorySream para el archivo. Trata asigando la extención .xls

Comment: yo quiero que se descarge como csv no xls